# Prioritize TLSv1.2 in nginx conf ssl_protocols

Tags: nginx, ssl

Snippet from nginx conf:

```
server {
  ssl       on;
  ssl_protocols         TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ...
```

Is there a way to set this up to force the use of TLSv1.2, and if not supported by the client then to fall back to TLSv1.1 / TLSv1?

Or is TLSv1.2 already used by default?

Comment: It seems to be automatic. Make sure you use "ssl_prefer_server_ciphers". It's not directly related to the procotol, but it's in the same area http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers,

Answer (score 2):

The highest protocol version supported by both ends of the connection will be used.  So, by default, TLS v1.2 will be used.

The reason why you need to turn off spectacularly insecure protocols like SSLv2/3 is because of downgrade attacks; an intermediary can modify the SSL connection negotiation to force the use of a less secure protocol.  There's nothing you can do about that except to not support the older protocols, because you never get told that the other end supports a better one (because the malicious intermediary has removed that information).

Answer (score 0):

is default, your rule of server specifies about ssl protocols is configured to support those out of the box:

- we don't want to use SSLv2 (insecure) or SSLv3 (exploitable)

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

Comment: I want to make sure that even though TLSv1, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.2 are enabled, TLSv1.2 will always be used by default if it is supported, and if not, fall back to TLSv1.1 or TLSv1. Is that the case?

Comment: the connection is set by:  server and client (with the protocol) , this graph will help you more to follow your issue into area ... http://blog.haproxy.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/ssl_handcheck2.png

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason for believing otherwise, generally systems that support TLS would support TSLv1.2.

So if at all possible, I would instead use:

`ssl_protocols TLSv1.2`

If that isn't possible, then I would use:

`ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1`

`TLSv1` could also be used in the second case (in place of the more specific versions), but this way, you ensure the order of preference.
I sort of assume TLSv1 would normally prefer 1.2 over 1.1, but being explicit about it can't hurt.

See [Mozilla's TLS config generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) for an set of recommendations about your more general TLS setup.

Comment: Is there an ordering preference with `ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1` as opposed to lets say `ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2`? This isn't the first time I've read that but there's nothing in the official documentation about an ordering preference (as far as I can see).

Comment: I am not sure what the 'official' answer would be, but yes, I would tend to think so. As with ciphers, for example, I assume you present first what you want to use, and then fallbacks you are willing to support. So 1.2 first, then 1.1